# Prove that $f \left(\lambda x + (1- \lambda )x' , \lambda y +(1- \lambda )y' \right) > \min \{f(x,y), f(x',y')\}$

Tags: functions, inequality, contest-math

> Let $f(x,y)=xy$ where $x,y\geq 0$. Prove that the function $f$ satisfies the following property: $$f \left(\lambda x + (1- \lambda )x' , \lambda y +(1- \lambda )y' \right) \geq \min \{f(x,y), f(x',y')\}$$
>    for all $(x,y) \neq (x',y')$ and $ \forall\; \lambda \in (0,1)$

This is a problem from an olympiad book. My try:
The left side of the inequality is a quadratic in $\lambda$ i.e. $$ (x-x')(y-y')\lambda^2 + \left\{(x-x')y' + (y-y')x'\right\}\lambda + x'y'$$ I'm unable to find the minimum value of above quadratic in $(0,1)$. Also, how to deal with $\min{\{xy,x'y'\}}$.

Thank you.

Comment: The equality holds also if $x=x’=0$ or $y=y’=0$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Thanks.. edited the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To simplify, let $m:=\min\{xy,x'y'\}$.

We can write $f \left(\lambda x + (1- \lambda )x' , \lambda y +(1- \lambda )y' \right)$ as:

\begin{eqnarray}
f \left(\lambda x + (1- \lambda )x' , \lambda y +(1- \lambda )y' \right) & = & 
(\lambda x + (1- \lambda )x')(\lambda y +(1- \lambda )y')\\
& = & \lambda^2xy+\lambda(1-\lambda)(xy'+x'y)+(1-\lambda)^2x'y'
\end{eqnarray}

Now we prove $xy'+x'y\geq 2m$, looking at all possible cases:

1. $x\geq x',y\geq y'\Rightarrow xy'\geq x'y', x'y\geq x'y'\Rightarrow xy'+x'y\geq 2x'y'=2m$
2. $x\leq x',y\leq y'$. Very similar to case 1.
3. $x\geq x',y\leq y'$. Note $$
   0\geq (x-x')(y-y')=xy-(x'y+xy')+x'y'\\
   \Rightarrow x'y+xy'\geq xy+x'y'\geq 2m
   $$
4. $x\leq x',y\geq y'$. Same as case 3.

We have $xy'+x'y\geq 2m$ and $xy\geq m, x'y'\geq m$, and since $(x,y)\neq (x',y')$, some of the inequalities will be strict. Hence
\begin{eqnarray}
f \left(\lambda x + (1- \lambda )x' , \lambda y +(1- \lambda )y' \right) & = & 
\lambda^2xy+\lambda(1-\lambda)(xy'+x'y)+(1-\lambda)^2x'y'\\
& > & m\lambda^2+2m\lambda(1-\lambda)+m(1-\lambda)^2\\
& = & m(\lambda+(1-\lambda))^2\\
& = & m
\end{eqnarray}